# Angular Countdown with rxjsTimer / observable subscribe

Tags: angular, timer, rxjs, observable, subscription

With Angular5.

I'm working on a livechat.

User can chat til the countdown reach 0.

On first user's input, the countDown start:

```
private engage_session() {

if(!this.is_engaged){

  this.countDown = Observable.timer(0, 1000)
    .take(this.counter)
    .map( () => --this.counter );   

  this.countDown.subscribe( remaining_credit => { this.remaining_credit = remaining_credit } );  
}

this.is_engaged = true;

}
```

I need to subscribe to the countDown so that i can use it in another func :

```
public sendMessage(message: Message): void
  {
    this.engage_session();

    if (!message) { return; }

    this.socketService.send({
      from: this.tokenUser.username,
      content: message,
      created_at: moment().format(),
      remaining_credit: this.remaining_credit || this.counter,
    });
    this.messageContent = null;
  }
```

I also have somthing like this in template:

```
 CountDown : <span class="badge badge-light">{{countDown | async | formatTime }}</span>
```

**Problem is: when i subscribe to countDown, the timer goes twice as fast as it should be.**

But when I remove the line:

```
this.countDown.subscribe( remaining_credit => { this.remaining_credit = remaining_credit } );
```

then the countdown is working fine..

Thanks for your help =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It goes twice as fast, most likely, because you subscribe it twice (`async` is your second subscription). I am not fully aware of your structures and implementation, but I think you could simply do:

`CountDown : <span class="badge badge-light">{{remaining_credit | formatTime }}</span>`

If this HTML is from component which creates`countDown` observable